# jquery toggleClass with fade in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to toggle between my light theme and dark theme:

```
$(".theme__switch").on("click", () => {
  $("body").toggleClass("light__theme dark__theme");
});
```

My goal is to attach a fade-in animation to both these classes.

It works for `light__theme` on load, and when I toggle back from `dark__theme`, but when I try to add the fade-in animation to my `dark__theme`, the animation doesn't work for either themes

I start with: `<body class="light__theme">`

```
.light__theme {
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
      opacity:0;
  }
  to {
      opacity:1;
  }
}
```

which works fine, but when I try to attach the animation to my
`dark__theme` class like so:

```
.dark__theme {
  --background: #121212;
  --text: #f2f3f4;
  background: var(--background);
  
  // adding the animation in
  animation: fadein 2s;

}
```

I don't get the fade-in animation, and it also removes the animation from my light theme.

The classes are being toggled correctly, I can see that when inspecting the `<body>` in dev tools, but I'm not sure whats causing my issue. Perhaps the way I'm calling the animation in my css?

I'd really appreciate any help on this one.. thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `reverse` to the `animation` for `dark__theme`:

```
.dark__theme {
  --background: #121212;
  --text: #f2f3f4;
  background: var(--background);
  
  // adding the animation in
  animation: fadein 2s reverse;

}
```

[Animation MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)